# Difference in socket.io client behavior for browser vs server

Tags: node.js, http, socket.io

I am wondering if someone has used the socket.io-client library for communicating between servers instead of communicating between browsers to server.

1. Is this kosher?
2. Is the behavior of the library pretty much the same when the client library is running on a server vs running in the browser?
3. Can the socket.io-server library initialize connections with clients, or do socket.io-clients need to initialize connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this kosher?

Yes, that is exactly what the socket.io-client is designed for.  It works great for communicating between two servers.

> Is the behavior of the library pretty much the same when the client
>   library is running on a server vs running in the browser?

Yes, the behavior is identical.  The only difference under the covers is that the browser implementation is built on top of the browser's webSocket support whereas the server-side client uses the socket.io webSocket implementation.

> Can the socket.io-server library initialize connections with clients,
>   or do socket.io-clients need to initialize connections?

Only socket.io servers are "listening" for incoming connections.  Somebody has to connect TO the socket.io server.  You can't connect TO a socket.io client.  A client must connect to a server.  So, a socket.io client (which can be either in a browser or on a server) must be the one that creates the connection.  Once connected, data can be sent either way on that connection.

Comment: @AlexMills - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are talking about the JavaScript version of the socket.io-client:

1. Yes, of course it is legitimate to use it server-side. it is just a "client" library, not only a "client-SIDE" library.
2. The behavior is the same, yes.
3. Clients need to initialize connections.

There is a server side usage example the [Socket.io-client documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client)

Other versions of the socket.io-client are also available in different languages (swift, java, CPP), that you can find on their [Github page](https://github.com/socketio).